# Remove style from card view (radius/elevation)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-styles

I want to remove the corner radius from the card view.
I tried this:

```
card:cardCornerRadius="0dp"   
card:cardElevation="0dp"
```

but no change.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove card_view:cardCornerRadius attribute from xml and try again.
 No need to assign it 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"`instead of `card:cardCornerRadius="0dp"`